# How do I make gdbinit compatible for both Android gdb and Linux host?

Tags: android, linux, gdb

I have a `~/.gdbinit` defined:

```
set disassembly-flavor intel
set serial baud 115200
set pagination off

#layout asm
#layout reg

layout src
```

However when I run `arm-linux-androideabi-gdb` it complains about multiple lines, many features are simply unsupported.

So is there a way to make that gdbinit "selectively" enable features?

Or any other approaches that make it work both ways (just don't complain and execute next few lines)

Comment: A very crude, absurdly custom, but workable solution might be the hexedit the binary and change "gdbinit" to some other filename of the same length in one of your gdb's.  The gdb documentation actually mentions a few oddball gdb variants built with custom names for their init file.  Or you can change the command lines (possible with a wrapper script) to tell it not to load any init files, and to explicitly load a custom command file instead.

Comment: As a workaround maintain multiple scripts, and start gdb with -x option ($gdb -x=<gdb-init-script>).

Comment: If your gdb has python, you could have `~/.gdbinit` contain the line `python import os; gdb.execute("source "+os.environ['HOME']+'/.gdbinit_'+gdb.TARGET_CONFIG)`, which would source another command file that you customized for a particular target.